# Problems with reading and writing to text files in python

Tags: python

I am trying to take an input and write the input to a text file to keep it stored. However, I can't seem to get the user input written over to the text file. Here is my code:

```
SaveUsername = open(r"C:\Users\Ty\Desktop\Login_sys\SaveUsername.txt","w+")
SavePassword = open(r"C:\Users\Ty\Desktop\Login_sys\SavePassword.txt","w+")
NewUsername = input("Please enter a username: ")
NewPassword = input("Please enter a password: ")
SaveUsername.write(NewUsername)
print (SaveUsername.readline())
SavePassword.write(NewPassword)
print (SavePassword.readline())
```

I am printing the readline to see if the code gets written and it never does.  Please help, thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you open the files in a text editor? Does it contain the text you wrote to it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should close the file after you write to it before reading the changes. You should also use `with open(...)` as it is a better practice (for multiple reasons). 
Here is the code you should use:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Ty\Desktop\Login_sys\SaveUsername.txt", "w") as SaveUsername:
    NewUsername = input("Please enter a username: ")
    SaveUsername.write(NewUsername)

with open(r"C:\Users\Ty\Desktop\Login_sys\SavePassword.txt", "w") as SavePassword:
    NewPassword = input("Please enter a password: ")
    SavePassword.write(NewPassword)

with open(r"C:\Users\Ty\Desktop\Login_sys\SaveUsername.txt", "r") as SaveUsername:
    print(SavePassword.readline())

with open(r"C:\Users\Ty\Desktop\Login_sys\SavePassword.txt", "r") as SavePassword:
    print(SavePassword.readline())
```

Answer (score 0):

Close a file & open for reading before reading it.

Comment: I will try that -- That fixed it! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
with open(r"SaveUsername.txt","w+") as SaveUsername:
    NewUsername = input("Please enter a username: ")
    SaveUsername.write(NewUsername)

with open(r"SavePassword.txt","w+") as SavePassword:
    NewPassword = input("Please enter a password: ")
    SavePassword.write(NewPassword)


with open(r"SaveUsername.txt" as SaveUsername:
    print (SaveUsername.readline())

with open(r"SavePassword.txt") as SavePassword:
    print (SavePassword.readline())
```